# Are there comments in command-line mode?

Tags: command-line, comments

Does VIM support comments in command-line mode?

I have tried the most popular variants including .VIMRC comments but neither worked:

```
:echo "hello" // echo usage
:echo "hello" /* echo usage */
:echo "hello" "echo usage
```

Or do the comments in this mode just don't fit in the VIM paradigm?

**Update**:
It seems there is a problem with the commands that end with ". Because all the others work, e.g. copying a buffer content:

```
:let @a=@0 " buffer copying
```

There must be some escaping. The suggested solution with |" seems to work for

```
:echo "hello" |" echo usage
```

but doesn't work for user-defined commands (those that are defined in .vimrc and whose names start with a capital letter) e.g.

```
:SearchHyphenation " user-defined
```

Comment: Try this: `:echo "hello" |" echo usage`.

Comment: @user938271 Thank you. Seems to work. "echo" is the output and the part starting with |" is ignored. However it doesn't work with user-defined commands (those whose names should start with a capital letter)

Comment: It works if the command was defined with the `-bar` attribute; otherwise with `:exe`: https://0x0.st/irhy.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vimscript does have comments and they're started by the `"` character.

They always work at the beginning of the line:

```
" echo usage
echo "hello"
```

They *sometimes* work inline, but not always. It depends on the command.

See [`:help :comment`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html?#%3Acomment), which says:

> `"` after a command causes the rest of the line to be ignored.  This can be used
>   to add comments.  [...]
>
> It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command  [...] and a few others (mainly commands that expect expressions) that see the `"` as part of their argument:
>
> - `:argdo`
> - `:autocmd`
> - [...]
> - `:echo` (and the like)

Comment: Ok. I see it now. It's not possible to append a comment to such a command.